# Angular js chart is not displaying in page. what could be the reason?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, charts

This is my code in view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "graph";
}
<link href="~/Content/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Site.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-chart.js"></script>

<h2>graph</h2>


 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerynew") 
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-chart.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appl" ng-controller="PolarAreaCtrl">


    <canvas id="polar-area" class="chart chart-polar-area" data="data" labels="labels">g</canvas>

</div>

<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div  ng-controller="g" >
Test: {{ 1+2 }}
        </div>

</div>
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

This is my code in sitejs file:

```
angular.module("appl", ["angular-chart.js"]).controller("PolarAreaCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales", "Tele Sales", "Corporate Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100, 40, 120];
});

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("test", function ($scope) {

});
app.controller('g', function ($scope, $http) {

});
```

But when i run the application, nothing is coming in page. what is the reason ?
I want graph based on the values in controller.
Am new to this angular js as well as angular graphs.
Please help me on this.

Comment: The reason will be available in `console`

Comment: It looks like you render scripts multiple times, like the `<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")`, the bootstrap.css and the angular-chart.js